# How do I enqueue a script to run inside the Gutenberg editor?

Tags: actions, wp-enqueue-script, block-editor

I'm using the Gutenberg editor as a replacement for a whiteboard in a classroom. I'm able to make the classroom more interactive by having students work directly inside the Gutenberg editor. As a long-term user of Wordpress it's truly wonderful to see this happen, with non-tech-savy users able to interact with the editor so easily.

To provide some missing functionality I'd like to run a custom script inside the editor. It's a simple script which adds some styles if certain conditions are fulfilled. I currently run this script on the front-end using `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` which is loaded onto the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook.

Is it possible to load this script inside the Gutenberg editor, so that while my students are editing the post we can also have the script working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using the Gutenberg editor as a replacement for a whiteboard in a classroom. I'm 
>   able to make the classroom more interactive by having students work directly inside the 
>   Gutenberg editor.

What a cool use of WordPress you describe there!

> Is it possible to load this script inside the Gutenberg editor, so that while my students are editing the post we can also have the script working?

It seems that WordPress 5.0+ will provide us with two hooks for this:

```
/**
 * Fires after block assets have been enqueued for the editing interface.
 *
 * Call `add_action` on any hook before 'admin_enqueue_scripts'.
 *
 * In the function call you supply, simply use `wp_enqueue_script` and
 * `wp_enqueue_style` to add your functionality to the block editor.
 *
 * @since 5.0.0
 */
do_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets' );
```

and also for both editor and front-end:

```
/**
 * Fires after enqueuing block assets for both editor and front-end.
 *
 * Call `add_action` on any hook before 'wp_enqueue_scripts'.
 *
 * In the function call you supply, simply use `wp_enqueue_script` and
 * `wp_enqueue_style` to add your functionality to the Gutenberg editor.
 *
 * @since 5.0.0
 */
 do_action( 'enqueue_block_assets' );
```

Update: From the [Gutenberg Handbook](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/packages/packages-blocks/#getting-started):

> The `enqueue_block_editor_assets` hook is only run in the Gutenberg
>   editor context when the editor is ready to receive additional scripts
>   and stylesheets. There is also an `enqueue_block_assets` hook which is
>   run under both the editor and front-end contexts. This should be used
>   to enqueue stylesheets common to the front-end and the editor.

So you could try to enqueue your scripts in the callback of either of those hooks as needed. It's also possible to add specific blocks as dependency.

Comment: That looks perfect. I tried adding it without success. Do I need to wait for 5.0 in order to use this?

Comment: Got it working now. Thank you very much! I've actually created a custom block for what I wanted to do. You pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can enqueue any style or script using this hook- **enqueue_block_assets**. The script/style inside this hook works for both backend & front end. So, the example will be something like the following codes-

```
function sgb_external_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'frontend-js',
    plugins_url( $sharedBlockPath, __FILE__ ),
    [  'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-components', 'wp-i18n' ],
    filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $sharedBlockPath )
  );
 }
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'sgb_external_scripts' );
```

You can apply a trick to enqueue any style/scripts just for backend/editor. In this case, it will look like the following codes-

```
function sgb_external_scripts() {
 if( is_admin() ){
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'frontend-js',
        plugins_url( $sharedBlockPath, __FILE__ ),
        [  'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-components', 'wp-i18n' ],
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $sharedBlockPath )
      );
 }
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'sgb_external_scripts' );
```